# adding login function in custom salesforce webservice

Tags: web-services, authentication, salesforce

I have a custom salesfoce webservice, but to access that webservice we need to login from salesforce enterprise wsdl. but i dont want to add that wsdl file. Is there any way to add login function on custom webservice or login with out that wsdl webservice???

Answer (score 2):

Yes, see [SOAP request to APEX webservice without requiring authentication](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/SOAP-request-to-APEX-webservice-without-requiring-authentication/m-p/182072#M29154).

> go into the site detail page in setup, click Public Access Settings,
>   and then add the Apex Class there.  This is effectively granting your
>   anonymous running user account (guest license) the ability to directly
>   access this class.

There are more detailed instructions at [Public Web Services via Apex and Force.com Sites](http://bitplex.me/2010/10/public-web-services-via-apex-and.html).

**Note that your data exposed via this web service will no longer be secure**.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But what i want to do is. I have created custom webservice in salesforce and downloaded wsdl file in my C# project. i want to use that wsdl file to access salesforce. but to gain access we have to use access salesforce using salesforce default wsdl (enterprise or partner). And i dont want to use that wsdl. What i want is to implement default wsdl's login function in my custom wsdl file. Is there any way to do that????

Answer (score 1):

As you mention, you need to authenticate, the login method is not included in the custom apex WSDL, you have lots of choices, depending on exactly what sort of app you're building.

1. Add either the enterprise or partner WSDL to your app and call login from there.
2. Use an [interactive OAuth](http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2011/03/digging-deeper-into-oauth-20-at-salesforcecom.html) flow which will result in you getting an access token & instance Url, which you can then use with the apex WSDL.
3. Use a [programamtic OAuth](https://help.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/remoteaccess_oauth_username_password_flow.htm) flow (username/password), again resulting in an access token * instance Url which you can then use with the apex WSDL.
4. if you have a web based app, you can create a custom link/tab in salesforce to pass you an existing serverUrl/sessionId info.

For the OAuth flows, you would pass the received access token in your apex requests as the sessionId (just like if you got it from login), and you would combine the host name from the instance URL with the path from the apex WSDL to set the endpoint URL of your stub.